# MsTest ignoring assemblyRedirect in app.config

Tags: redirect, app-config, .net-assembly, mstest

I have a project that I recently upgraded the json nuget package to v10.
The same project also has a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting (via Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3 package) - which references json v6.0 dll.

I have an app.config in the test project that has:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" 
     culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

When I run the tests in VS, all tests pass.

But when I run the same tests using MsTest command (ver 12 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE), a bunch of test methods fail with the exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

This is the exact line in the test method where it fails:

```
HttpRequestMessage.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new HttpConfiguration());
```

I have checked my entire solution and confirmed that none of the projects have any reference to json v6.

Is there a reason why the redirects are being ignored when I use MsTest ?
(I can see the testProjectName.dll.config with the redirect in the bin folder of the test project too)

Also, I read that using a testsettings file can resolve this issue, but I am unclear what I need to have in my testsettings file to redirect to the newer json.

Comment: Got a little bit further by adding json 6 dll as a deployment item in testSettings. The only issue I see now is: Just a handful of tests fail. And all of them fail with error: Error: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Newtonsof
t.Json.JsonSerializerSettings System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.get_SerializerSettings()      I am assuming the System.Net.Http calls the method:get_SerializerSettings() which is not present in json v10 anymore.

Comment: Ever figure this out? I have a similar problem.

Comment: If I remember it correctly, I added an app.config to all projects that were using System.Web.Http/AspNet.WebApiClient (that had a dependency on json 6) to redirect to json 10. (Some of the projects were missing the app.config file)